# Unable to connect ADB to Android Marshmallow (6.0.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, android-6.0-marshmallow, mtp

I'm on a MacBook running macOS Sierra and I'm having trouble connecting Android Studio to the phone. The phone is a Samsung Galaxy A3 (2016) running the latest update - Android 6.0.1.

I've tried listing the devices using the command `adb devices`, but the list is empty.

When I connect the device I can hear a tone and the phone is charging. I do not get a notification when connecting the device, hence trying to tap on the notification and somehow forcing an MTP connection is impossible.

I've already activated the Developer Options and the **USB configuration** mode is set to **MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)**. When trying to cycle through the available USB modes, if the phone is connected to the computer, it always reverts back to MTP automatically.

Trying to turn off and back on the USB debugging, or the Developer options didn't work. Also restarted both the phone and the computer but nothing changed.

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?
From my research, the only thing that seems to have worked for other people is to tap the notification that is supposed to appear when I connect the phone to the computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are You sure that the cable is not broken?

Comment: I'm an Android developer and I have multiples phones with multiple cables. After testing 5 cables, the 6th worked flawlessly.

Comment: I have also tested every combination of phone<->cable possible and noticed that 4 out of 6 cables do not work in any phone, 1 cable works on one phone (and it's not the original cable) and 1 cable works on every phone (an old cable from a Nokia I no longer have).
I've noticed that some cables don't fit the phone's USB port so nicely. They fill a bit loose.
Also (of-topic), I'm always complaining of the original iPhone cable but I guess shitty cables are just standard

Comment: So, the problem was the broken/bad cable?

Comment: Yes, it was. I was just presenting my defence so I don't feel so dumb :)
Also, this is the first time I didn't find an answer and needed to ask a question. I don't see the option to accept or up vote your answer.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Comments != Answers. Still, I think there should be possible to up vote a comment.
@Kamiccolo: Do want to create the answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the cable is broken or just plainly wrong. Changing the cable should help.